# JAVA give each char of a String a numeric value

Tags: java, string, char, each

1st of all, sry about my english.

I´m trying to get each letter of a String, and, for each letter, give some int value.

Ex: name = Joao.
J=3, o=1, a=4, o=1.

I´m gona use this numbers later to some calculations.

that is what i get so far:

```
static String separador(String nome){
        name = nome;
        char[] letras;
        letras = name.toCharArray();
        int qtd = letras.length;
        String fullName = "";

         for(int i=0; i<qtd; i++)
        {
            fullName = fullName + " " + letras[i];
        }

         return fullName;

    }
```

this get me each char separatedly. but can get the rest.

can someone help me?

Comment: You should improve your question. We need more information to help you to get exactly what you want.

Comment: How do you assign these values : "J=3, o=1, a=4, o=1" ? Is there any special requirement when selecting values or are they random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a map which will store all characters ( A to Z) and corresponding numbers like :

   ```
   Map m = new HashMap();
   m.put('A', 0);
   m.put('B', 1);
   ```
2. Iterate over the characters of your input and check whether that character exists in the above map or not . if it exists then create a 2nd map add that char to that 2nd map

   ```
   static String separador(String nome){
   name = nome;
   char[] letras;
   Map tempMap = new HashMap();
   Map m = new HashMap();
   m.put('A', 0);
   m.put('B', 1); 
   letras = name.toCharArray();
   int qtd = letras.length;
   String fullName = "";

    for(int i=0; i<qtd; i++)
   {
     if(m.containsKey(letras[i])
       tempMap.put(letras[i], m.get(letras[i]))
   }

    return tempMap;
   ```

   }

Comment: tnk you very much my friend, it helps alot. But I´m getting some trouble to show all characteres of the word. 

Ex: if the name is antonio, it show me on the size() = 5, coz char N and char O is repeating. I need to show all the chars and values of the name, even if it was duplicated.

there´s a way to it?

tnk very much.

Comment: Oh yeah..Sorry Buddy.. I missed it . In that case Map will not work as map doesn't allow duplicate key. So instead of using the 2nd tempMap you can use Arraylist.

                `if(m.containsKey(letras[i]) {
                   String s = String.valueOf(letras[i]) + " --- " + new           Integer(m.get(letras[i])).toString();
                  tempList.add(s)
 }`